# Adapt size of an icon (from an icon-font) on a responsive image

Tags: html, css, sass

here's a problem i'm look for a neat solution to:
I want to position an icon out of an icon-font which is located at a pseudo-element on an image.
This image behaves responsibly (it shrinks down on smaller viewport and grows on bigger viewports until it's reached its original size).

What I want the icon to do is more or less to behave the same as the image. That means it should shrink and grow accordingly to the viewport until the maxwidth of the image is reached.

I'm having a hard time finding a solution to this cause it seems to me that the only property on the size of the icon is "font-size" which is not very flexible.
It can be adjusted using media queries, but that doesn't sound to good to me. What I'm looking for is something like "background-size: cover;"

I know there are many ways to solve these, for example put the icon as a part of the graphic, but i have not yet given up finding a solution using an icon font on this problem.

Markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="image">
   <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500/500">
   <span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#x002b;"></span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
//include icon-font
@font-face {
 font-family: "icons";
 src: url("https://css-tricks.com/examples/IconFont/fonts/IcoMoon.woff") format('woff');
}
//set icon on pseudo-element
[data-icon]:before {
 font-family: icons; 
 content: attr(data-icon);
 speak: none; 
 //define size of icon
 font-size: 9em;
}
.wrapper {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 0;
 display: inline-block;
}
//position icon absolute on img
.image span {
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 10;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

img {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}
```

and here's a fiddle: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L8krqo0e/)

So if anybody could help, i'd be thankful.